# FAVICON: Favicon not showing up

Tags: favicon

I'm using a .png favicon file and it is not showing up on my site.

Doing a grep, I see the following in home.htm which looks right for me(I have also confirmed it's in the HEAD section within home.htm):

```
home.htm: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

The favicon.png file is in the same directory as the home.html file.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks all.

In case the file info is revealing for anyone, I'll attach it here:
[image]

Comment: Apache? Nginx? Lighttpd?

Comment: LAMP stack.  I wouldn't expect the versions matter, but if they do, I can provide that.

Comment: I'm not sure that browsers look for favicons real time - I think they may cache the results.  I added one to a site recently and refreshed and diddled with everything - nothing worked.  Then someone else told me they saw the favicon - I go and check and boom it's there.

Comment: Hmm... that's helpful feedback.  Maybe I already have it correct.  I'll try clearing my browser cache.

Comment: I cleared the cache in both Firefox and IE and still don't see the favicon.  That was a good point though.

Comment: Have you tried using a .ico instead to make sure it's the .png and not configuration / browser / etc.? Also, what software did you use to make the .png?

Comment: Yes, I did try an .ico and that worked.  I'm not sure what the issue is with the .png or the link directive I had set for it.  I made the .png in photoshop but didn't use any plugins for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll ad my voice to the chorus and say the problem is that it's not in ICO format. Take a look here for a Photoshop plug-in: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html

Comment: Yes, I did try an .ico and that worked.  I'm not sure what the issue is with the .png or the link directive I had set for it.  I made the .png in photoshop but didn't use any plugins for it.  I would still like to be able to use the .png format so I know how.  The .ico I made was with IcoFx(16x16-True Color).

Answer (score 3):

Not all browsers support showing png type of favicon. You may want to check the wiki page for support table.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: You're right.  I should have noted originally that I am using Firefox and the version of IE I am using is newer and also supports png's

Answer (score 0):

You've checked that the file does actually exist, and that's about all you can do besides wait. Browsers are very fickle about grabbing and updating favicons. It'll show up eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page out (http://ma.tt/2003/11/how-to-create-a-favicon/) its what i use to create favicons had the same issue as you with regard to png files now just stick with ico.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like .ico is the way to go.  I appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I used the first answer and it worked. Well sort of. I reloaded the page in Safari on my iPhone -> add to home screen--> icon not there. But after I saved as a bookmark in Safari and as a bookmark in Chrome, the favicon was there next to the folder. Not sure yet why it didn't on iPhone.